# How to modify an OpenWrt package for experimentation

Tags: openwrt, debug

OpenWrt documentation is very fuzzy on how to make quick changes to a package for development or experimentation. Are there step-by-step instructions on how to modify a package from the standard OpenWrt repository?

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** OpenWRT release `23.05.2`, `ipq806x` architecture and package
`odhcpd-ipv6only` are used as an example.

1. Unpack SDK

```
cd ~/
tar xf openwrt-sdk-23.05.2-ipq806x-generic_gcc-12.3.0_musl_eabi.Linux-x86_64.tar.xz
mv openwrt-sdk-23.05.2-ipq806x-generic_gcc-12.3.0_musl_eabi.Linux-x86_64 sdk
cd ~/sdk
```

2. Create feeds.conf:

```
cp feeds.config.default feeds.config
```

modify feeds.config to minimum for faster build:

```
src-git-full base https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt/openwrt.git;openwrt-23.05
src-git packages https://git.openwrt.org/feed/packages.git^8e3a1824645f5e73ec44c897ac0755c53fb4a1f8
```

3. Update feeds

```
./scripts/feeds update -a
```

4. Configure build

```
./scripts/feeds install odhcpd-ipv6only
```

5. Update .config

```
make menuconfig
```

- "Network" Make sure odhcpd-ipv6only is selected

6. Build

NOTE: even odhcpd-ipv6only was selected, the package name is still odhcpd

```
make -j $(nproc) package/odhcpd/compile
```

7. If the build is successful, create a copy of the package source from downloaded archive.

   NOTE: There are safeguards in the OpenWrt build process for preventing
   source code from beeing modified.  A copy is needed to make changes to it.

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src/
tar xf ~/sdk/dl/odhcpd-2023-10-24-d8118f6e.tar.xz
mv odhcpd-2023-10-24-d8118f6e odhcpd # just to shorten the name
cd odhcpd
```

8. Set `STAGING_DIR` env variable and update the `PATH`

```
export STAGING_DIR=~/sdk/staging_dir
PATH=$STAGING_DIR/host/bin:$PATH
```

9. Examine the contents of the package folder to get a clue how to build it.

```
ls ~/sdk/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a15+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/odhcpd-ipv6only/odhcpd-2023-10-24-d8118f6e
```

You can deduce that odhcpd uses cmake with ninja

10. Clone CMakeCache.txt from the successful build folder and make necessary
    adjustments to it.

```
cp ~/sdk/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a15+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/odhcpd-ipv6only/odhcpd-2023-10-24-d8118f6e/CMakeCache.txt .
```

11. Edit CMakeCache.txt

- Replace all occurrences of

```
sdk/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a15+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/odhcpd-ipv6only
```

with

```
src
```

- Also replace all occurrences of

```
odhcpd-2023-10-24-d8118f6e
```

with

```
odhcpd
```

- Add the following library path to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING` definition

NOTE: It is a mistery how this entry is added during the native OpenWrt build
process. If someone has an idea, please comment.

```
-L/home/user/sdk/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a15+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/usr/lib
```

It should look something like this:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=-L/home/user/sdk/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a15+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/usr/lib -DPIC -fpic -specs=/home/user/sdk/include/hardened-ld-pie.specs -znow -zrelro
```

- Change `-Os` to `-Og` in `CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING` to skip the compiler optimization

```
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=-Og -pipe -g3 -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -mfloat-abi=hard -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DPIC -fpic -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro
```

12. Try to build

```
cmake .
ninja -v
```

Hopefully it was a success.

13. Make changes to C code in src folder
14. Rebuild

```
ninja -v
```

15. Copy the built binary to the rowter

```
scp odhcpd router:/tmp
```

16. Use remote debugging

a) Start gdbserver on the router

```
gdbserver :1234 /tmp/odhcpd
```

b) Connect to gdbserver from the build client to debug.
(An explicit IP address is needed because gdb cannot resolve the router address)

```
~/sdk/scripts/remote-gdb 192.168.0.1:1234 ~/src/odhcpd/odhcpd
```